# I need to reload the previous page to 'another URL' when I click on back button in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

Suppose now I'm in `google.com` the I typed `facebook.com` in same page then from this page I clicked `browser back` button, then I need to load `gmail.com`  `instead of` `google.com`. 
I need `JavaScript/JQuery code` to this.

Anyone please help regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(performance.navigation.type == 2){
 window.location.replace("www.google.com");
}

 </script>
```